# Eliminar segunda página en blanco al imprimir en modal

Tags: javascript, css, css3

un modal para se más exactos, cada vez que quiero imprimir se genera una segunda hoja en blanco ¿Que podría estar mal?

O existe alguna forma que solo se imprima la primera hoja automáticamente o eliminar todo contenido en blanco.

Lo que está dentro se imprimirá en una ticketera, lo cual no tiene formato A4 sino un formato sin fin.

```
                        <div id="facturamodal" class="modal modal-edu-general default-popup-PrimaryModal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-close-area modal-close-df">
                                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" id="modalimprimir">
                                <center>
                                   <div id="absolute30">
                                    <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
                                </div>
                                </center>
                                </div>
                                   <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" href="#">Cerrar</a>
                                  <a  id="imprimir"class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" href="#">Imprimir</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<script>
    document.getElementById("imprimir").onclick = function () {
        printElement(document.getElementById("modalimprimir"));
    }

    function printElement(elem) {
        var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

        var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

        if (!$printSection) {
            var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
            $printSection.id = "printSection";
            document.body.appendChild($printSection);
        }

        $printSection.innerHTML = "";
        $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
        window.print();
    } </script>
```

Comment: Prueba eliminar aquella cadena de `<span>`s.

Comment: Esa cadena es un loader, a través de una consulta con ajax  se cambia todo el div interno por una respuesta.